# How to change the master-page of VersionDiff.aspx in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have designed a custom master page in Sharepoint online if I select my custom master page in system master page section(Site Settings->Site Master Page Settings->Specify a system master page), the master page will be applied to all the SharePoint inbuilt pages. But I want to apply custom master page only to VersionDiff.aspx. Is there any way that, I can apply custom master page only for VersionDiff.aspx in SharePoint online. I want to write some custom coding on this page. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can open that page in SharePoint Designer and see if you can edit the Custom Master Page url from there? If not, then you may need to put some logic in a page itself to change the custom master page programatically.

I am not sure how to do that at this moment though